# Working with Mountain Lion's Notification Center using PyObjC

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, pyobjc, nsusernotification

I'm trying to send notifications to Mountain Lion from my python script and react to clicks on the notifications. Sending the notifications works perfectly find by now. But yet I was not able to get Lion to call back my script upon a click.

Here is what I do. I implemented a Notification class. The only purpose of an instance of that class is to provide notifications by invoking `notify()`. In the same method I set the object the app's delegate.

```
import Foundation
import objc
import AppKit

class MountainLionNotification(Foundation.NSObject, Notification):

    def notify(self, title, subtitle, text, url):
        NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
        NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')
        notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
        notification.setTitle_(str(title))
        notification.setSubtitle_(str(subtitle))
        notification.setInformativeText_(str(text))
        notification.setSoundName_("NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName")
        notification.setUserInfo_({"action":"open_url", "value":url})
        AppKit.NSApplication.sharedApplication().setDelegate_(self)
        NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().scheduleNotification_(notification)

    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
        userInfo = sender.userInfo()
        if userInfo["action"] == "open_url":
            import subprocess
            subprocess.Popen(['open', userInfo["value"]])
```

Now I expected `applicationDidFinishLaunching_()` to be called upon a click on the notification. Unfortunately that never happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried to add a decorator `@objc.signature("v@:^@")` to the delegate method, without success.

Comment: Now I also tried to set my `MountainLionNotification` object the default notification center's delegate and implement the protocols `userNotificationCenter_didActivateNotification_()` method. Stil no success!

Comment: Hey, were you able to get notifications to show from just a python script/interpreter without starting the event loop? I can't seem to even get notifications showing using the code above

Comment: @GP89 - You definitely need to start the event loop; there's no way around it.

Comment: @koloman Where did you get Notification from in
class MountainLionNotification(Foundation.NSObject, Notification) ?

Comment: if you have an answer for Catalina please post on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234033/how-create-local-notification-on-macos-catalina-pyobjc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, found it. Didn't run `AppHelper.runEventLoop()`. Obviously a facepalm mistake. The following code works:

```
class MountainLionNotification(Foundation.NSObject, Notification):

    def notify(self, title, subtitle, text, url):
        NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
        NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')
        notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
        notification.setTitle_(str(title))
        notification.setSubtitle_(str(subtitle))
        notification.setInformativeText_(str(text))
        notification.setSoundName_("NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName")
        notification.setHasActionButton_(True)
        notification.setOtherButtonTitle_("View")
        notification.setUserInfo_({"action":"open_url", "value":url})
        NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().setDelegate_(self)
        NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().scheduleNotification_(notification)

    def userNotificationCenter_didActivateNotification_(self, center, notification):
        userInfo = notification.userInfo()
        if userInfo["action"] == "open_url":
            import subprocess
            subprocess.Popen(['open', userInfo["value"]])
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm getting the errors: `objc.BadPrototypeError: Objective-C expects 1 arguments, Python argument has 5 arguments for <unbound selector notify of MountainLionNotification at 0x10bf48650>`, and `Notification is not defined`. Do you know if these can be fixed?