# NSUserNotificationCenter not showing notifications

Tags: nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I'm not sure if I got something wrong but from the examples I could find. I wrote that little helloworld.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSUserNotification.h>


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSUserNotification *userNotification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    userNotification.title = @"Some title";
    userNotification.informativeText = @"Some text";

    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:userNotification];

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with:

```
cc -framework Foundation -o app main.m
```

It compiles and I can execute it but it won't show anything. For some reasons, nothing gets presented. I read that Notifications may not get displayed if the application is the main actor. How can I make it show Notification?

Answer (score 7):

set a delegate and override

```
- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center 
                               shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification {
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: could you add a complete sample, i'm not sure to understand where to put that line.

Comment: Great thanks for this. It's interesting that if you do not set the delegate and implement this method, the notification is visible in Notification Center, but does not get displayed.

Comment: @Ants how to set delegate in python

Answer (score 1):

For a complete example in Objective-C and Swift:

We need to provide a `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, in the simplest case we can use `AppDelegate` for this

## Objective-C

We need to modify `AppDelegate` provide `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` method.  From a clean `AppDelegate` (which looks like this...)

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
```

We'd modify it to be:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

Now we can provide the required delegate method inside `@implementation AppDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center 
                               shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification {
  return YES;
}
```

## Swift 4

You can use an `extension` of `AppDelegate` to provide `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` methods:

```
extension AppDelegate: NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to assign a new identifier for any new notification. A notification will only show once, unless a new identifier is used or the user clears their notification history.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question - but as there may be people looking for an answer how to do this in Python & PyObjC I will post the correct syntax here (as it's one of the top google results). As I can't comment on imp's comment I will post this as another answer.

It's possible to do the same in Python with pyobjc this way:

```
def userNotificationCenter_shouldPresentNotification_(self, center, notification):
    return True
```

Full class would look like this:

```
from Cocoa import NSObject
import objc

class MountainLionNotification(NSObject):
    """ MacOS Notifications """
    # Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202983/working-with-mountain-lions-notification-center-using-pyobjc

    def userNotificationCenter_shouldPresentNotification_(self, center, notification):
        return True

    def init(self):

        self = super(MountainLionNotification, self).init()
        if self is None: return None

        # Get objc references to the classes we need.
        self.NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
        self.NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')

        return self

    def clearNotifications(self):
        """Clear any displayed alerts we have posted. Requires Mavericks."""

        NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')
        NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()

    def notify(self, title="", subtitle="", text="", url=""):
        """Create a user notification and display it."""

        notification = self.NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
        notification.setTitle_(str(title))
        notification.setSubtitle_(str(subtitle))
        notification.setInformativeText_(str(text))
        # notification.setSoundName_("NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName")
        notification.setHasActionButton_(False)
        notification.setActionButtonTitle_("View")
        # notification.setUserInfo_({"action":"open_url", "value": url})

        self.NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().setDelegate_(self)
        self.NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().scheduleNotification_(notification)

        # Note that the notification center saves a *copy* of our object.
        return notification
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the code on here but was unable to get a notification to work.  It turned out that because I was on multiple monitors I needed to check the "When mirroring or sharing the display" option to get the alerts to present themselves.  After that the python code worked.

[image]