# Throwing a MacOS notification from a minimal standalone Objective-C program?

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, notifications

I'm trying to implement push notifications on MacOS within a C codebase. Ideally, there'd just be one Objective-C file containing (1) a public C function I can call and (2) some Objective-C code I can use to throw a notification. This way, the source files can be compiled and linked seamlessly in the build process.

Toward this end, I've been trying to create a minimal example that can throw notifications with just a single `.m` file (not an entire XCode project), much like the one discussed in [NSUserNotificationCenter not showing notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896348/nsusernotificationcenter-not-showing-notifications). However, two problems:

1. I still can't get the code to work despite trying the solutions in the aforementioned link. It compiles and runs but does not throw a notification.
2. If possible, we'd like to switch to the [new user notifications API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications?language=objc). Not a big deal if this isn't possible for now, though.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSUserNotification.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center 
                               shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification {
  return YES;
}

- (void)throwNotification {
    NSUserNotification *userNotification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    userNotification.title = @"Some title";
    userNotification.informativeText = @"Some text";

    printf("trying to throw {%s %s}\n", [[userNotification title] UTF8String], [[userNotification informativeText] UTF8String]);

    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:userNotification];
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    AppDelegate *app = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [app throwNotification];

    return 0;
}
```

This is compiled with `cc -framework Foundation -o app main.m`.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code you tried (I mean, probably you have already added something to the example code behind the link)

Comment: @kirjosieppo thanks, i added an example. i'm completely new to objective-c, so apologies in advance if it's just completely incomprehensible :')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultNotificationcenter returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460372/nsusernotificationcenter-defaultnotificationcenter-returns-nil)

Comment: Not voting to close, but you should take a look at the topic @Petesh linked to below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712535/mac-mountain-lion-send-notification-from-cli-app Specifically, you should embed an `Info.plist` file into your binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in order to display a notification, you need to have [a proper bundle identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712535/mac-mountain-lion-send-notification-from-cli-app?rq=1).

We're going to take a [bit of the code from here](https://github.com/norio-nomura/usernotification), where we wait for the notification to get displayed. We can embed an Info.plist file into the compiled binary, which will accomplish the same thing as the swizzling code in a file called `notify.m`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL keepRunning;

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        AppDelegate *appdel = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
        app.delegate = appdel;
        NSUserNotificationCenter *nc = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
        nc.delegate = appdel;
        appdel.keepRunning = TRUE;
        NSUserNotification *userNotification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
        userNotification.title = @"Some title";
        userNotification.informativeText = @"Some text";

        [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:userNotification];
        while (appdel.keepRunning) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center
                               shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification {
  return YES;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didDeliverNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
{
    self.keepRunning = NO;
}

@end
```

I construct an `Info.plist` file consisting of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.finder</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

> Please use an appropriate bundle identifier, as `com.apple.finder` will cause all these notifications to appear to come from macOS Finder, which might be confusing to users.
> I then compile it using:

```
clang -o notify -framework Cocoa notify.m -Wl,-sectcreate,_\_TEXT,__info_plist,Info.plist
```

> there's a `\` in that build line to avoid the markdown parsing of the underscores, but it's not needed for the actual build command line.

Comment: Instead of hacking around `NSBundle`, why not embed a proper `Info.plist` into the tool directly? (e.g. https://pcable.net/posts/2020-11-14-inetaccesspolicy/ — with `-ldflags='-extldflags "-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist $(shell pwd)/Info.plist"'`)

Comment: Or better yet: do as the commend on the top answer in that linked question suggests, and set the `CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY` flag during compilation to automate this.

Comment: Cool - I'll update my answer - they're looking for a solution that doesn't use xcode, though so the CREATE_INFOPLIST… might not be ideal

Comment: Ah, good point. And the updated suggestion look excellent! (Though I would suggest calling out that you shouldn't _actually_ use `com.apple.finder` as a bundle identifier, but come up with your own.) +1